# Wordpress / Acf Query Posts by a custom field and order them by another

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Here's my problem , I have a custom post type "Emissions" , and i wrote a query to get all posts where the day field is equal to today , and where the field hour is inferior to current time , so that the query is for displaying the "Upcoming" ,

up to that , i'm good , but when it comes to ordering the posts by the field hour , in an ascending order , the output isn't ordered at all , is there any problem with my code ?

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' =>3,
'post_type'     => 'emissions',
'meta_query'    => array(
    'relation'      => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'       => 'jour',

        'value'     => $lyoum,
        'compare'   => '='
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => 'horaire',
        'value'     => $douka,
        'compare'   => '<',
        'order_by'      => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC',
    )
));
```

if anyone wants to help , that would be great ,

ps : variables are

$lyoum = $today , datetime getting the current day,

$douka = $now ,datetime getting the current time,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your order parameters are misplaced in the `WP_Meta_Query` args. They instead belong in the main `WP_Query` args. You also need to specify the meta key to order by.

```
. . . 
'post_type'     => 'emissions',
'meta_key'      => 'horaire' // specify which key to order by.
'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num', // move from WP_Meta_Query.
'order'         => 'DESC', // same as above.
'meta_query'    => array(
. . .
```

Comment: Still the same, when i did your code , i got 19:30 then 22:00 , then 13:00


Thanks for helping me out by the way :)

Comment: Ah, you're ordering by meta_value_num therefore the colon will be an issue. One thing I didn't pick up on previously is the incorrect parameter name too. orderby is all one word.

Comment: don't worry , i didn't "copy paste" all the code you gave me , i just picked up the idea and wrote the query from scratch , still didn't work :(

Comment: isn't there a parameter , like meta_value_datetime or something ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I'd look at changing the way you're storing times in the meta value. Maybe as a pure number then formatting with the colon on output. Failing that I think you're going to have to write custom order functionality

Comment: So is should either change the Acf plugin function where it stores the datetime , or create a field that uses a different type ?

Comment: Are you storing it as a full datetime string? From your earlier answer I got the impression you were simply storing it as hh:mm

Comment: No no , it's storing as a full datetime , yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss , i juste write the short format answer to save time :)

Comment: I'd say you have two options. #1 - custom WPDB query allowing you to order by datetime or #2 - change the stored value to a UNIX timestamp